# Last minute change in Lambda syntax or gcc bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, c++11

I use the svn-version of the **gcc-4.7.0** to check out some C++11 features, e.g. Lambda Expressions. Since a couple of weeks some of my old examples including Lambdas to not compile anymore. I wonder:

- Did I miss a last-minute change in the C++11-Lambda-spec that has been implemented in gcc-4.7.0 in the last weeks?
- Is it a bug in gcc, that does not recognize inline-Lambdas anymore?
- Or did I misunderstood something else with Lambda-syntax?

The problematic code seems to involve inline-Lambdas that are provided as arguments directly.

**Would you say that the following code is correct C++11 code?**

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

struct Image {}; // dummy

void fill(int color, const Image& image) {
} // dummy

int main() {
    int red;
    Image img;
    thread th{
        [&img](int c){ fill(c, img); },  // error?
      red };
    th.join();
}
```

If I change it and assign the Lambda to a variable first it works:

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

struct Image {}; // dummy
void fill(int color, const Image& image) {
} // dummy

int main() {
    int red;
    Image img;
    auto f = [&img](int c){ fill(c, img); }; // lambda
    thread th{ f, red };                     // ok now
    th.join();
}
```

I put an example [here](https://ideone.com/NrnTT) where both compiles with gcc-4.5 (except that it raises an exception, probably because `-pthread` is not linked). But as I said: In my gcc-4.7.0-svn the first variant stopped compiling a couple of weeks ago.

**Update** The error message seems to be a parse error:

```
In function 'int main()':
...:30:11: error: expected '=' before '(' token
...:30:12: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
...:30:12: error: expected ')' before 'int'
...:30:36: error: no matching function for call to 
           'std::thread::thread(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
...:30:36: note: candidates are:
           ...
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: Sorry, of course. update...

Comment: What if you parenthesize the lambda? ([&img](int c){ fill(c, img); })

Comment: Yes! `thread th{ ([&img](int c){ fill(c, img); }), red };` works. Hmmm... Should this be this way?

Comment: @VaughnCato that should be an answer

Comment: @Sam Miller: Not quite. I don't think that it is required by the Std to put the Lambda in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the grammar defined in the draft n3242, this code is valid C++11. A `braced_init-list` is composed of a list of `initializer-clause`, which can be `assignment-expression`s or themselves `braced_init_list`s. An `assignment-expression` can be a `lambda-expression`, which is exactly what you have as a first element (`[...](...){...}`).

Therefore, surrounding the lambda with parentheses should not be required, if think you can safely file a bug report :). (Of course, this answer is based on a draft, so the possibility of a late change in the grammar is not to be excluded.)

Comment: There no changes between N3242 and the ISO version I could find, concerning Lambdas.

Comment: I think it has been 'officially' confirmed that the N3242 was word-for-word identical to the C++11 standard document by many members of the committee (apart from the front cover :))

Comment: N3242 isn't even word-for-word identical to N3290 (the FDIS, final draft submitted for approval). So I don't see how it's identical to the final standard.